# Smooth a timestamped series of translation and quaternion samples

Tags: ros, trajectory, transforms

I have a rosbag of transforms (of type `TransformStamped`) I'd like to smooth a small amount without altering the overall trajectory much, just reduce the higher frequency noise.  Each consists of a translation xyz and rotation quaternion, but it's easy to convert to rotation matrix if that's more convenient- ideally I'd pass in the whole sequence to a function with some parameters and get the smoothed sequence returned.  The raw data is in ROS but the solution doesn't have to use ros datatypes.

I could resample the sequence to have exact intervals if that helps, they are around 10Hz but I could use the tf lookup interpolation to make it 10 Hz precisely.  Everything is already in a fixed reference frame.

Something in python would be preferred over C++, maybe there is a simple 6dof moving average function in numpy/scipy I could start with?

Decoupling the rotation from translation could be fine, the smoothing of the translation would be trivial and then I'd just need a way to smooth a sequence of quaternions.

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm or for actual code?

Comment: In order of preference: mature code in an established library, code in a random github or body of answer here, description of how it could be done

Comment: Ok.  Any information on the kinematic environment?  E.g. max joint velocities/accelerations?